# error 415: Unsupported Media Type (Calling WCF in HTML5 using jQuery .)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, wcf

I have tried all the replies on stackoverflow but still I am getting same error.
I have used basicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding. but both are not working.

Here is my Code :-

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>


<compilation debug="true"/></system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    <services>
            <service name="HTMLConnWCF.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HTMLConnWCF.IService1"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**IService1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace HTMLConnWCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        UserProfile VelidateUser(UserProfile userProfile);

    }

    [DataContract]

    public class UserProfile
    {

        [DataMember]

        public string userId;

        [DataMember]

        public string passWord;

        [DataMember]

        public string firstName;

        [DataMember]

        public string lastName;

        [DataMember]

        public string middleName;

        [DataMember]

        public string userName;

        [DataMember]

        public string userEmail;

    }

}
```

**Service.cvc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace HTMLConnWCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    //[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public UserProfile VelidateUser(UserProfile userProfile)
        {

            if (userProfile == null)
            {

                return null;

            }

            else
            {

                if ((userProfile.userId.ToLower() == "admin") && (userProfile.passWord.ToLower() == "admin"))
                {

                    UserProfile currentuser = new UserProfile();

                    currentuser = userProfile;

                    currentuser.firstName = "TEJAS";

                    currentuser.middleName = "RAJENDRABHAI";

                    currentuser.lastName = "PATEL";

                    return userProfile;

                }

                else
                {

                    return null;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML File: -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>

<title>Login Page</title>

<!--<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="../STYLES/LOGINFORMSTYLE.CSS" />-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="MyFileJS.js">

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="registration">

<h2>Login Account</h2>

<form id="registerUserForm">

<fieldset>

<p>

<input id="txtUserName" type="text" required="required" autofocus="true" placeholder="User Name"  />

</p>

<p>

<input id="txtPassword"  type="password"  required="required" placeholder="Password" />

</p>

<p>

<input type="button" id="submitForm" autofocus="false" />

</p>

</fieldset>

</form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**MyFilejs.js**

```
var Type;

var Url;

var Data;

var ContentType;

var DataType;

var ProcessData;

//Generic function to call AXMX/WCF  Service

function CallLoginService() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({

        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb

        url: Url, // Location of the service

        //data: Data, //Data sent to server
        data: "{'name':'" + "mohit" + "','age':'" + "12" + "'}",
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server

        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server

        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False

        crossDomain: true,

        success: function (msg) {

            //On Successfull service call

            ServiceSucceeded(msg);

        },

        error: ServiceFailed  // When Service call fails

    });

}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {

    if (DataType == "json") {

        resultObject = result.VelidateUserResult;

        if (resultObject) {

            var userdata = JSON.stringify(resultObject);

            sessionStorage.userInforamtion = userdata;

            window.location = "ExercisePage2.htm";

        }

        else {

            alert("Invalid User");

            $('#txtUserName').val("");

            $('#txtPassword').val("");

        }

    }

    else {

        alert("Result Data type is not JSON");

    }

}

function ServiceFailed(result) {

    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);

    Type = null; Url = null; Data = null; ContentType = null; DataType = null; ProcessData = null;

}

function VelidateUser() {

    var request = { userProfile: { userId: $('#txtUserName').val(),passWord: $('#txtPassword').val()} };

    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(request);

    Type = "POST";

    Url = "http://localhost:53119/Service1.svc/VelidateUser";

    Data = jsondata;

    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    DataType = "json";

    ProcessData = true;

    // Call the Web Service....

    CallLoginService();

}

$(document).ready

(

function () {

    $('#submitForm').click

(

function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    VelidateUser();

}

);

}

);
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't close my question if my question is match with other questions. I have tried all the duplicate question but still i am facing same issue.

Comment: what are your: input/output, i.e. *actions* that produce the *wrong result*